# How can I preview TeX formulas inline in arbitrary modes?

Tags: auctex, tex

How can I get TeX previews inside modes other than AUCTeX or org-mode? I'd love to see TeX equations in jabber, erc and markdown. If I ever switch to Emacs for email, I'd presumably like to see previews there too.

Comment: I have not tried this, but you might want to look at `mmm-mode` which allows multiple major modes in a buffer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tried to re-use AUCTeX [preview-latex](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html) but failed and gave up.

[Org-mode also provide the same feature](http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html#Previewing-LaTeX-fragments). Turns out [weechat](https://github.com/the-kenny/weechat.el/blob/master/weechat-latex.el) managed to re-use it to automatically show latex preview.

I've extracted the preview part from weechat in a separate file which you can get on [this repo](https://github.com/aaptel/preview-latex/). It's also available as the `px` package on MELPA (I've just submited it).

There are 4 entry points which can be called interactively:

- `px-preview`: render all latex fragments in the current buffer.
- `px-preview-region`: render fragments in the region.
- `px-remove`: remove all previews from the current buffer (restore the text).
- `px-toggle`: toggle display of previews in the current buffer.

As long as org-mode previewer works, this one should.

Since the code is still pretty small I'll include it below, but please install the package or use the repo.

```
;;; px.el --- preview inline latex -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

;; Most of this code comes from weechat-latex.el which in turn uses
;; org-mode previewer.

;; Copyright (C) 2014 Aurélien Aptel <aurelien.aptel@gmail.com>
;; Copyright (C) 2013 Rüdiger Sonderfeld <ruediger@c-plusplus.de>

;; This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
;; it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;; the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;; (at your option) any later version.

;; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;; GNU General Public License for more details.

;; You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;; along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

(require 'org)

(defvar px-temp-file-prefix "px-"
  "Prefix for temporary files.")

(defvar px-temp-directory-prefix "px-"
  "Prefix for temporary directory.")

(defvar px-image-program org-latex-create-formula-image-program
  "Program to convert LaTeX fragments.
See `org-latex-create-formula-image-program'")

(defvar px-temp-dir nil
  "The temporary directory used for preview images.")

(defun px--create-preview (at)
  "Wrapper for `org-format-latex'.
The parameter AT should be nil or in (TYPE . POINT) format.  With TYPE being a
string showing the matched LaTeX statement (e.g., ``$'') and POINT being the
POINT to replace.  If AT is nil replace statements everywhere."
  (org-format-latex px-temp-file-prefix
                    px-temp-dir
                    'overlays
                    "Creating images...%s"
                    at 'forbuffer
                    px-image-program))

(defun px--set-temp-dir ()
  "Set `px-temp-dir' unless it is already set."
  (unless px-temp-dir
    (setq px-temp-dir
          (make-temp-file px-temp-directory-prefix
                          'directory))))

(defun px-preview ()
  "Preview LaTeX fragments."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
      (px--set-temp-dir)
      (org-remove-latex-fragment-image-overlays)
      (px--create-preview nil))))

(defun px-preview-region (beg end)
  "Preview LaTeX fragments in region."
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((math-regex (assoc "$" org-latex-regexps))
         (regex (nth 1 math-regex))
         (n (nth 2 math-regex))
         matches)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char beg)
      (while (re-search-forward regex end t)
        (setq matches (cons (cons "$" (match-beginning n)) matches)))
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
        (px--set-temp-dir)
        (dolist (i matches)
          (px--create-preview i))))))


(defun px-remove ()
  "Remove LaTeX preview images."
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (org-remove-latex-fragment-image-overlays)))

(defun px-is-active? ()
  "Are LaTeX Previews currently displayed?"
  org-latex-fragment-image-overlays)

(defun px-toggle ()
  "Toggle display of LaTeX preview."
  (interactive)
  (if (px-is-active?)
      (px-remove)
    (px-preview)))


(provide 'px)
```

Comment: I am getting following error: `Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-latex-fragment-image-overlays`

Answer (score 0):

[`texfrag.el`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) renders LaTeX fragments in buffers whose major mode is registered as or derived from a major-mode in `texfrag-setup-alist`. It uses `preview.el` from AucTeX for generating the overlays with the LaTeX images.

`texfrag.el` works out of the box for doxygen comments in major modes derived from `prog-mode`.

You can install `texfrag.el` from [`melpa-stable`](https://stable.melpa.org/#/?q=texfrag) via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `texfrag` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `texfrag-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> to activate the preview.
You get the Preview menu with all the items of the AUCTeX preview package.

Note, that `texfrag` also works for editing html source, eww, and org-mode.