# Is it possible to preview TeX formulas automatically on auctex-mode?

Tags: latex, auctex, preview-latex

In `auctex` mode, whenever I write a new formula I have to type `C-c C-p C-p` to render it as an inline image.

I'm wondering if it's possible to automatically render the formula or equations as I write them in the buffer (similar to how flyspell highlights misspelled words)?

Comment: Maybe with a timer, but consider a continuous compilation might slow down the editing process.

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/rich-text-format-for-latex-in-emacs/12795#12795

Comment: See also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/219/