# Rich Text Format for LaTeX in Emacs

Tags: latex

I have seen that the online LaTeX editor [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) has a nice Rich Text format so instead of this:

[image]

you see this:

[image]

You can also see it for yourselves without any login required if you go in the website and press "Create New Paper".

How can I add this functionality in Emacs?

In case it is relevant I already use AUCTeX.

Comment: Ctr-C Ctr-p Ctrl-p enables a preview (using preview-at-point). give that a try.

Comment: @user2699 I know about the preview, which is different from what I ask, and not helpful. It does that only for a specific area and after the user's instructions. What is more it creates a lot of useless files.

Comment: Why did someone downvoted my question? It is both valid and perfectly structured!

Comment: Well, there's really no magic in there. Something has to render the image you are seeing, and the reason it's not rendered immediately as you type is because it's costly to do that. Also, it makes little sense to render when the document is not valid (which is most of the time during editing). Theoretically, you could us a timer to update a buffer displaying a DVI produced from a TeX file you edit, but I'm not sure how that would behave in practice. My guess is that it would work better for small documents and would be a pain when the document would take a lot of time to compile.

Comment: @wvxvw It sounds painful. :P

Comment: Is preview-latex (part of auctex) https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html relevant?

Comment: px package is another option http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/219/. It is available from melpa.

Answer (score 3):

One partial answer is [latex-pretty-symbols.el](https://bitbucket.org/mortiferus/latex-pretty-symbols.el/src/f2056f85be402a1c365d688a4a04ba82d01fdc60/latex-pretty-symbols.el?at=default).  It doesn't produce images, and just uses Unicode instead, so it doesn't look as pretty as the screenshot posted in the question.  However, if the OP does not want to generate images, it may be the best way to go at present.