# How to render latex expressions (not necessarily formula) inside buffer?

Tags: latex, preview-latex, previewing

By `preview-latex` on can render latex formulae inside a `tex` buffer. The package `px` package renders latex formular inside an arbitrary buffer (see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/219/).

A similar question: How to render latex expressions (not necessarily formulae) inside buffer? For example to render something like `\textbf{some text...}`.

Comment: Turn on tex macros.

Comment: @Dan How to turn tex macro? I tried `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-tex-macros)` with no effect.

Comment: Am away from my computer for a few days so can't check myself, but look in the auctex manual.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. I found it! Putting `(require 'tex-fold)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-fold-mode)
` in .emacs then `M-x TeX-fold-buffer` can do what I was looking for. (Note the command is `M-x TeX-fold-buffer` not `M-x tex-fold-buffer`).

Comment: Great!  Go ahead and post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Putting

```
(require 'tex-fold) 
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-fold-mode)
```

in .emacs then `M-x TeX-fold-buffer` (or the shortcut `C-c C-o C-b`) can do what I was looking for.