# How to make orgtbl-mode use org-entities in other major modes?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Org mode provides a variable called `org-entities` that contain replacements for latex symbols like `\alpha, \beta` etc.

Org also provides a minor called `orgtbl-mode` which allows text that starts with a `|` in arbitrary major modes to be interpreted as an org table and then I can do calculations and alignment. I have found this to be a very useful feature.

However `orgtbl`doesn't seem to use `org-entities` when I am using it while documenting some math heavy python code. For example I have a function with some detailed logic that I need to program and it would be helpful to get the same kind of feedback while writing my code's documentation that I get in a org buffer. Please let me know how I can achieve this effect. Thanks.

Below is a small table fragment that orgmode renders automatically that contains some "business logic" that I need to code:

```
| Name      | Symm      | Remarks               |
| \equiv    | \check    | x = y                 |
| \neg      |           | x \cap y = \phi \land x \cup y = D |
| \perp     | \check    | (else)                |
```

Comment: Can px-mode http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/219/ help? It is also available via melpa. In can render latex symbols in arbitrary mode.

Comment: Oh yeah that would be great. I'll try it.

Comment: I haven't installed `px` but it seems that previewing latex using `px` would require the user to call `px-preview-region` before the latex is rendered and also it would need to be enclosed in `$..$`. I would prefer to find a solution that is more automatic just like the behavior of `org-mode`. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a minimal example of your orgtbl document ?